# how can I download files with < 1MB?

Tags: python

I am trying to download 1MB pdf files from given path , but the issue with my code . it is download more than 1MB . how can I fix it?

```
try:
  response = requests.get(href, stream=True)
  total = response.headers.get('content-length')
  if len(total) > self.MAX_SIZE:
    print "maximum size (%d kbs)" % (self.MAX_SIZE/1024)
  else:
    if total is None:
      pass
    else:
       os.system('wget -P %s %s'%(PATH, href))
except Exception as e:
  pass
```

Comment: Try using `chunk_size` with `iter_content`. See [Chunk-Encoded Requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests)

Comment: You should check the value of `len(total)`. It might not be what you expect.

Comment: let me rephrase, I want to download only files with < 1MB

Comment: Python can download files. No need for wget

Answer (score 0):

`total = response.headers.get('content-length')`
is the string represent the length of your content you should convert to a number before comparing it.

```
if int(total) > self.MAX_SIZE:
```

There is another problem with your code is `response = requests.get(href, stream=True)` is bad for performance - you are downloading the whole file before comparing, should use `response = requests.head(href)` to retrieve the `Content-Length` if that's the only thing you need.

Comment: how am I downloading before comparing?

Comment: @azdejo you are comparing but the value you used `len(total)` is wrong, because it returns the length of the string. Change to my statement above: `if int(total) > self.MAX_SIZE:`

It should fix your problem, other comment is for performance improvement

Comment: I changed to `if int(total) > self.MAX_SIZE:`, but how am I download first before comparing? on the other hand if its None breaks the program.

Comment: `response = requests.get(href, stream=True)` this line, python will download it to get the response with body. That's why I suggest to change to `response = requests.head(href)`